# reverse output after loop in a c program

Tags: c, string, loops, substring, reverse

i do this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *str, c;
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Inserisci stringa principale : ");

        while (c != '\n') {
        // read the input from keyboard standard input
        c = getc(stdin);

        // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
        str = (char*)realloc(str, y * sizeof(char));

        // store read character by making pointer point to c
        str[x] = c;

        x++;
        y++;
        }

    str[x] = '\0'; // at the end append null character to mark end of string

    printf("\nLa stringa inserita : %s", str);

      char *sub, b;
      int w = 0, z = 1;

      sub = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

      printf("Immetti sottostringa da cercare : ");

          while (b != '\n') {
            // read the input from keyboard standard input
            b = getc(stdin);

            // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
            sub = (char*)realloc(sub, z * sizeof(char));

            // store read character by making pointer point to c
            sub[w] = b;

            w++;
            z++;
          }

      sub[w] = '\0'; // at the end append null character to mark end of string

    char *p1, *p2, *p3;
    int i=0,j=0,flag=0, occurrences=0;

      p1 = str;
      p2 = sub;

      for(i = 0+1; i<strlen(str); i++)
      {
        if(*p1 == *p2)
          {
              p3 = p1;


              for(j = 0;j<strlen(sub);j++)
              {
                if(*p3 == *p2)
                {
                  p3++;p2++;
                } 
                else
                  break;
              }
              p2 = sub;
              if(j + 1 == strlen(sub))
              {
                 flag = 1;
                 occurrences = occurrences + 1;
                printf("\nnel numero di volte : %d\n",occurrences );
                printf("\nSottostringa trovata all'indice : %d\n",i );
              }

          }
        p1++; 
      }


      if(flag==0)
      {
           printf("Sottostringa non trovata");
      }
    free(str);
    free(sub);
    return (0);
    }
```

Which searches for a given substring in a string, once it finds print the locations where the substring is found and the number of times it is found, at present for example if my string is aaooaaoo and my substring or output outputs the positions , 3 and 7 and last 2 (ie the number of occurrences) I would need to get first 2 and then the positions in reverse order, ie in this case should print next to the 2nd before the 7 and then the 3, How could you do it?

Comment: This is your first logic error: `getc` returns `int`; you should follow suit and declare `c` as an `int`, because as it currently stands your code discards useful information. Namely, `EOF` (which you ignore, anyway) is not a character value; it's a failure code telling you "`getc` couldn't read a character". As a result, there are `UCHAR_MAX` character values which `getc` could return (more specifically, these are `unsigned char` values converted to an `int`) and one error code (which is distinct from the character values, being the negative value of `EOF`).

Comment: Your next logic error occurs in the line following the `getc` issue: `realloc` uses `size_t` for the second argument (which can't possibly have negative values), yet `y` is an `int` (which *can* have negative values). Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is unnecessary if you make `y` a `size_t`. Consider `str[x]` where `x` is negative, perhaps by means of an integer overflow condition... You should use `size_t` for all array indexes, rather than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

declare an array which is limited to your maximum amount of entrances, and a variable which means how many entances are found already, act something like this

```
const int max_entrances_amount = 1000;
int entrances_count = 0;
int entrances[max_entrances_amount];
```

when you have found an entrance of a substring, just do:

```
entrances[entrances_count++] = i; // position in a string;
```

after all actions, just output an array like

```
printf("entrances: %d\n", entrances_count);
for(int i = 0; i < entrances_count; i++)
    printf("%d ", entrances[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply store the positions using an array and print them out reversely in the end.

For example

```
if(j + 1 == strlen(sub))
{
  flag = 1;
  pos[occurrences] = i; // store the position in pos array
  occurrences = occurrences + 1;
}

...

// at the end
printf("%d", occurrences);
for (j=occurrences-1; j>=0; j--)
  printf(" %d", pos[j]);
```